# What is Perforce equivalent of the git commit hash

Tags: git, perforce

We need a way to identify the exact state of the source control repository used to build a binary from it. In Git land we can use Commit Hash to point to the state of the repository at a particular moment. What would be the closest equivalent of that in Perforce land?

Comment: The git way is to use labels and tags. That's a *lot* easier than searching through a myriad of hashes

Comment: Depending on requirement, the hash might be right what you need. Branches and tags can be moved around whereas the hash will never _ever_ change... _and_ the question is about a perforce equivalent for a git hash, anyway.